# How to kill a printing job on centOS

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, printing

How does one kill a printing job on centOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two command line interfaces to printing:

- In the BSD interface, use [`lpr`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lpr) to print, [`lpq`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lpq) to view pending jobs, [`lprm`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lprm) to cancel a job.
- In the System V interface, use [`lp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/lp.html) to print, [`lpstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/lpstat.1.html) to view pending jobs, [`cancel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/cancel.1.html) to cancel ongoing jobs.

There are several printing systems available for Linux and other unices. [CUPS](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php) is the most common one nowadays. It comes with a System V interface by default, and has a BSD interface that may or may not be installed. If you don't have CUPS and are running Linux or *BSD, you have a BSD system.

Different printing systems have different sets of options and other commands, but they are similar enough for simple cases. To cancel a printing job, use `lpq` or `lpstat` (whichever is available, or either if both are available) to see the job number, then `lprm` or `cancel` to cancel the job.

With CUPS, if you need to cancel a job really fast, `cancel -a` will cancel all your pending jobs. Most implementations of `lprm` will cancel the job currently printing on the default printer if called with no argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CUPS, you can manage jobs and do other things via the web interface at http://localhost:631. If you are not using CUPS, there are advantages to doing so, as it is now the printing standard, at least for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on what printing daemon you have installed, although if you're the one who started it, try opening a terminal window and typing `lpq` to see if the job you want killed is listed. If so, use `lprm queuenum` where `queuenum` is the number of the job in the queue that you want killed.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried lpq -a at first, but the system responsed with "no entries". Can you let me know why this happens and how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: That means that there aren't any entries in its print queue. Are you sure the job is still even on your system?